# How to determine $(\tfrac{-5}{p})$ $\mod 20$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

There was a question in a past exam paper that asked Find criteria $\mod(20)$ for determining the Legendre symbol $(\tfrac{-5}{p})$ where $p\geq 7$.

I am very confused by what this means as I understand it the Legendre symbol is implicitly working in  $\mod p$, how can we learn anything about $\mod 20$

Comment: This is a (routine) question about quadratic reciprocity.  Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Ah I see, That's actually next on my list to study , at least now I know where to look to solve such problems though thank you :)

Comment: In case the formulation is what confuses you: The question asks you to find $\left(\frac{-5}p\right)$ when you only know $p\bmod 20$.

Comment: I think you'll find that you can work this problem very quickly once you've got reciprocity down. Good luck!

Comment: @lulu I posted an answer could you take a look at it for me please :) ?

Comment: @excalibirr  I commented on your post. Do you understand what I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

From Hagen von Eitzen's Comment I believe the following is the correct method :

We're looking at all $p \geq7,$ in $\mod 20$ so then we have to consider $7,11,13,17,19$

say $p\equiv 7$ then we compute $(\tfrac{-5}{7})$

$$(\tfrac{-5}{7})=(\tfrac{2}{7})=1$$ as $7\equiv-1 \mod8$

Now consider $p\equiv11$

$$(\tfrac{-5}{11})=(\tfrac{6}{11})=(\tfrac{2}{11})(\tfrac{3}{11})$$

Note that $11\equiv3 \mod 8$ so we have

$$-(\tfrac{3}{11})=(\tfrac{11}{3})=(\tfrac{2}{3})$$

Where we took the first step here because by the quadratic law of reciprocity $(\tfrac{3}{11})(\tfrac{11}{3})=(-1)^{5\times1}=-1\Rightarrow (\tfrac{3}{11})=-(\tfrac{11}{3})$

$$(\tfrac{2}{3})=-1$$

as $3\equiv 3\mod 4$.

Now we just follow the same method outlined above for $p=13,17,19$and we're done!

Comment: Not sure I follow the game plan here.  The point is not to search the primes up to $20$.  The answer (they are implying) is that $\left(\frac {-5}p\right)=1$ for $p\equiv a,b,c \pmod {20}$ and $\equiv -1$ for $p\equiv f,g,h\pmod {20}$. Your job is to find $a,b,c,f,g,h$ (note: I don't mean to suggest that there are $3$ each here). Granted, it is not obvious that $20$ is the correct modulus here, but that will drop out of reciprocity.

Comment: @lulu I don't  isn't the above method finding those a,b,c's , f,g,h's for instance for $(\tfrac{-5}{7})=1$ so then why can't we say that $7=a$, I'm very confused by the formulation of this question...

Comment: To get you started:   You want to know, say, all the primes $p\neq 2,5$ for which $\left( \frac {-5}p\right)=1$.  Well $\left( \frac {-5}p\right)=\left( \frac {-1}p\right)\times \left( \frac {5}p\right)$ so we either need both factors to be $1$ or both to be $-1$.  Now, $\left( \frac {-1}p\right)=1\iff p\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so we understand that term.  QR tells us that $\left( \frac {5}p\right)=\left( \frac {p}5\right)$ so you just have to analyze that (which is easy!).

Comment: I'm sure your text goes through some similar examples in detail...this is an absolutely standard exercise in reciprocity.  If nothing else, the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) goes through several examples, including this one as it happens.  The technique is amazingly powerful...which is why Gauss' proof that it worked was such an impressive achievement.

Comment: @lulu would you by any chance have any links to sites or pdfs where such problems are solved, the only text I have is  a set of lecture notes and our lecturer didn't like to provide any examples

Comment: The [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Quadratic_reciprocity) is often a good place to start (though that link only gets you to a proof of the core result).  Any standard text or reference ought to go through several examples though...as I mentioned, the wiki article is a natural starting point.

Comment: @lulu I figured out how to do it :) thanks for your help !